# How can I align this longer span with the rest?

Tags: html, css

I have this name/value pairs:

[image]

As you've already noticed, name and state's values are both of them aligned on right side but address' value starts on new row.

***How can I align the span which contains the address*** like the rest values (yeah, it's longer, but it should start on the same row with **Address** and continue on the next one)?

Style of address:

```
<div class="prop">
   <span class="name">Address</span>
   <span class="value">Women and Gynae Oncology Centre Mount Elizabeth Medical Centre Mount Elizabeth #17-14</span>
</div>
```

CSS for name class:

```
.name {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 115px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  clear: left;
}
```

CSS for value class:

```
.value {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** After some refinements from the answer, it looks better:

[image]

Comment: You're aware that this is a situation (almost) perfect for a [definition list (`<dl>`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.prop {background: #eff9fe; overflow: auto;}
.name {float: left; width: 300px;}
.value {display: block; overflow: hidden; background: #e5f2f5;}
```

putting the width on the `.name` will help your 'columns' align, `overflow: hidden` and no float on `.value` should mean that if long text in there needs to wrap it will only wrap inside itself instead of under the "key"

#### Updated per comments

added `overflow:auto` to container div as this needs to contain the floated child, `float: left; width: 100%;` should also work if overflow causes unnecessary scrollbars (it shouldn't in this case but you know..)

**further update re alignment**

```
.prop {overflow: auto; padding: 10px 0;}
.value {display: block; overflow: hidden; background: #e5f2f5;}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 115px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: There is a single problem. Names are not always aligned now with the values.. For instance, `state` is not alligned with its pair value because address' value wrapped on multiple lines... Do you see a solution?

Comment: @Cristian `.prop {overflow: auto;}` - the float needs to be contained.. sorry missed that! will update answer too

Comment: @clairesuzy It's better now indeed but still a little bit of allignment. I've attache a photo in my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @clairesuzy Sorry, It works if I remove padding and margin from name and add padding-top to prop (for spacing between "rows". Thanks again.

Comment: remove the padding and margin from the left float and apply padding to the `.prop` div this will give consistent "gaps" between top/bottom of each pair

Comment: @Cristian we overlapped `:)` Glad it's sorted, I updated my answer again for completeness anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
.prop {
    overflow:auto;
}

.value {
    float: right;
    width:350px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/7L8kX/show/

Comment: doesn't work in IE7 and below - for them you can't right float a second in source element - it drops below the left content

Comment: you're Welcome, I think everyone's trying to forget about IE6/7 anyway `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having a wrapping issue.  The span isn't the issue, its your div (or your screen) is to small to hold the span on one line, so its wrapping.

What are you settings for your prop css class?